# Using named list to generate cases for case_when

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

I am trying to figure out how to use case_when for groups stored in a list so modifying the list will modify the result of the case_when.

Here is a toy test case:

```
library(tidyverse)
info <- tibble(target = letters[seq(1, 10)])

groups <- list("A" = letters[seq(1, 10, by = 3)],
     "B" = letters[seq(2, 10, by = 3)],
     "C" = letters[seq(3, 10, by = 3)])

info %>% mutate(case_when(
  target %in% groups$A ~ names(groups)[1],
  target %in% groups$B ~ names(groups)[2],
  target %in% groups$C ~ names(groups)[3]
))
```

This gives the output I want but I want to generate the options in the case_when dynamically from the list. I imagine it would be something like this:

```
generate_cases <- function(x, i) {
  ### I have no idea what to do here...
}


cases <- groups %>% imap(generate_cases)

info %>% mutate(case_when(!!! cases))
```

I suspect something use quo() and rlang::expr() but I really can't figure out how to string it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using the `purrr::imap` function

```
cases <- imap(groups, ~quo(target %in% !!.x ~ !!.y))

info %>% mutate(case_when(
  !!!cases
))
```

A better alternative might be to reshape your groups into a proper lookup table so you can do an efficent left-join. One way would be

```
info %>% 
   left_join(stack(groups), by=c("target"="values"))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using this in BigRQuery so I need the case_when solution; you can't have a local and remote data source for a join in BgiRQuery. However, the left_join is likely the better solution in other cases. This is a great answer, thanks!